# How to query for a co-occurence of events within elasticsearch?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, querydsl, eql

I'm trying to query for a co-ocurrence of events within a specified time range but can't seem to figure out how to actually perform such a query.

Consider, for example, that an excerpt of `Events` table looks something like this:

| `ID` | `@timestamp` | `event.action` | `agent.name` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14:12:00 | file-created | PC 1 |
| 2 | 14:15:00 | permissions-changed | PC 2 |
| 3 | 14:28:34 | created-process | PC 2 |
| 4 | 14:30:09 | logged-in-explicit | PC 3 |
| 5 | 14:43:02 | file-created | PC 3 |
| 6 | 14:52:43 | privileged-service-called | PC 3 |
| 7 | 14:58:27 | file-created | PC 2 |
| 8 | 15:01:28 | logged-in | PC 1 |
| 9 | 15:02:00 | permissions-changed | PC 1 |

**The goal is to create an alert that would be generated when both `file-created` and `created-process` occurs by the same `agent.name` within 60 minutes of each other.** The order of events does *not* matter. In other words, the above data should return two different alerts:

| `ID` | `@timestamp` | `agent.name` | `event.ids` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14:58:27 | PC 2 | `[2,7]` |
| 2 | 15:02:00 | PC 1 | `[1,9]` |

In SQL this could be accomplished by joining the `Events` table on itself, but this doesn't seem to be possible with Elastic. Elastic does have the `sequence` query option, but this naturally requires a predefined sequence of events rather than an unordered group of events. While this could be done with two sequences without *too* much additional overhead, things get rather complicated when looking for the co-occurrence of three or more event.actions.

I looked into using the threshold rule, but there doesn't appear to be a way to check if multiple distinct threshold values can be checked for on an aggregate scale. I've also looked into the aggregate rule, but this only seems to support numerical aggregation.

One thought I had was to attempt to use a form of bit-stuffing as a means of being able to sum an entire binary column and then perform a mathematical bit-masking operation to determine if the desired event.action exists in the index, but this would make it super un-readable and difficult to debug.

Here's a short example of what I mean:

##### Beginning of Bit Stuffing Example

> First, the mapping of the binary values:
>
> | `event.action` | `agent.name` | binary |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | file-created | PC 1 | `0000 0000 0001` |
> | permissions-changed | PC 1 | `0000 0000 0010` |
> | created-process | PC 1 | `0000 0000 0100` |
> | logged-in-explicit | PC 1 | `0000 0000 1000` |
> | privileged-service-called | PC 1 | `0000 0001 0000` |
> | logged-in | PC 1 | `0000 0010 0000` |
> | file-created | PC 2 | `0000 0100 0000` |
> | permissions-changed | PC 2 | `0000 1000 0000` |
> | created-process | PC 2 | `0001 0000 0000` |
> | logged-in-explicit | PC 2 | `0010 0000 0000` |
> | privileged-service-called | PC 2 | `0100 0000 0000` |
> | logged-in | PC 2 | `1000 0000 0000` |
>
> Then, convert (some of) the rows from the `Events` table:
>
> | ID | `@timestamp` | `event.action` | `agent.name` | binary |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 14:12:00 | file-created | PC 1 | `0000 0000 0001` |
> | 2 | 14:15:00 | permissions-changed | PC 2 | `0000 1000 0000` |
> | 3 | 14:28:34 | created-process | PC 2 | `0001 0000 0000` |
> | 7 | 14:58:27 | file-created | PC 2 | `0000 0100 0000` |
>
> Then the bitwise addition (`OR`ing) of the binary column:
>
> ```
>    0000 0000 0001
>    0000 1000 0000  
>    0001 0000 0000 
>    0000 0100 0000 
>  -----------------
>    0001 1100 0001
> ```
>
> Then with `0001 1100 0001` I can reference the mapping again to see that an alert *should* be generated since the 7th and 8th digit (from the right) are both true/1's.

##### End of Bit Stuffing Example

Apart from bit stuffing, another idea I had was to create a new index (something like `file-process-created alert` and then in the pipeline to that new index just query for two unique event.actions joined by agent.name. The issue with this idea is that it would ultimately generate an index per alert in addition to a rule searching for unique event.actions.

**Any other ideas/solutions on how to go creating a double query inside of an outer query?**

Comment: Please share your query.  This works much better if you create a dbfiddle for it.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to make a query for this.

Comment: This site isnt about writing the code for you.  Its about helping you with issues.  A good start is to put it into a dbfiddle, as suggested earlier.